# javascript on android

Tags: javascript, android, android-emulator

I have a menu in my webpage that drops down on Mouseover() event but this thing is not working on android browser? What may be the reason?

Answer (score 7):

There's no equivalent to a Mouseover on touch screens (maybe one day we'll have a finger over? :P).

You should change your javascript implementation to expand the menu on something more universal like a click event instead if you want functionality across multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

There are no MouseOver behaviors in touchscreen devices.

Comment: +1 for enjoying my humor :D.  And for having the correct answer of course.

Answer (score 1):

Android/touch screen devices only handle clicks.  You don't have anything to "hover" with (no cursor, at least).

Answer (score 1):

As many pointed out

> There's no equivalent to a Mouseover
>   on touch screens

Maybe this article will help you out a bit:

[JavaScript Touch and Gesture Events iPhone and Android](http://m14i.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events-iphone-and-android/)

It is a general overview that may come in handy.

Good luck